# pydb problems on invocation from MinGW and from Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, mingw

I am trying to run pydb 1.26 from emacs on a MinGW environment running in windows 7. The python I am currently running is python26 although I have tried this with python25 with the same results.  Reading the documentation and looking at the video seems to indicate that in order to start using pydb with GUD all I have to do is:  pydb myprogram.py

Unfortunately this is not the case. When I issue "pydb myprogram.py" in a shell inside emacs, I get:

```
 
pydb tetris.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/bin/pydb", line 19, in 
    import fns
ImportError: No module named fns
```

I have tried the altenative invocation of

python -t /c/python26/Lib/site-packages/pydb/pydb.py /c/fullpath/myprogram.py

which seems to satisfy all dependencies, however upon doing this, the OS seems to spawn the python process and but it never comes back.

Issuing either of these two invocations directly from emacs ( without the intermediate shell ) generates the same result.

What am I doing wrong? I am sure I had this working before but lost the environment due to a disk crash.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of confusion here. Also a lot of vagueness in terms of how you are set up in terms of how you got emacs, python and pydb installed.

pydb comes with GNU Emacs code that hooks into the Emacs Lisp package GUD (grand unified debugger). Let's leave that aside for the moment since that has nothing to do with your not being able to run pydb say in a emacs shell.

I'm assuming you install pydb from the source since there is no ez_install or egg for that. When you run the "configure" script as well as "make" install, there is a bit of information that's given that is telling you where it is going to install things and what's happening. Some of this is important to keep track of.

By way of example here is some of the information I got when running from a mingw terminal inside a VMWare image of Windows XP:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
configure.ac:120: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac:120: installing `./missing'
emacs/Makefile.am:22: installing `./elisp-comp'
...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode ...
checking for emacs... no
checking for xemacs... no
checking where .elc files should go... ${datadir}/emacs/site-lisp
checking for emacs... no
checking for emacs... no
checking where .elc files should go... (cached) ${datadir}/emacs/site-lisp
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.4.0... python
checking for python... /c/Python27//python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... win32
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}\Lib\site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}\Lib\site-packages
...
Now type `make' to compile
$
```

And when I run "make install" some of the output there is:

```
$ make install
Making install in test
...
test -z "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages/pydb" || /bin/mkdir -p "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages/pydb"
...
test -z "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages/pydb" || /bin/mkdir -p "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages/pydb"
...
if ! test -d "/usr/local/bin"; then \
      test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"; \
    fi
```

...

From the above, in my case you see that the package is installed in *c:/Python27/lib/site-packages*. You will probably have Python26 in there since you are using version 2.6.

Also, the above output shows me that the *pydb* script is installed in */usr/local/bin*.

Great. Now I need to make sure c:/Python27/lib/site-packages is set in the PYTHONPATH environment variable which gets fed into sys.path. To see what is in sys.path run:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
```

Since you were having problems you probably don't find where pydb is installed in sys.path. So to add that here is the export command I used:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH='c:/Python27/lib/site-packages/pydb;.'
```

Now when I run *pydb* which is located in */usr/local/bin* as "make install" indicated above, I get:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pydb  test/gcd.py 3 5
(c:\cygwin\home\rocky\src\external-vcs\pydb\test\gcd.py:10):  <module>
10 """
```

Don't worry about the cygwin stuff above, that's just where I have the Python script I want to debug located.

This was done inside a MinGW shell. To get running in an Emacs shell, it depends on how Emacs was compiled.

Finally after having written all of this let me say that both *pydb* and the Emacs code that hooks into GUD are now a bit deprecated. The newer and better debugger is pydbgr available from http://code.google.com/p/pydbgr/ and the new and better Emacs code is on github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr . Alas both of them require other Python or Emacs packages to be installed. On the Python side there are eggs to simplify this if you are *not* running virtualenv. On the Emacs side, packaging is alas more steps.